# Authors Using a Shared Pseudonym - BibTeX question

Tags: bibliographies

First of all, sorry if this is a repeat question or if this isn't the right place to ask.

One of my sources in a paper I'm writing is [Blanche Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanche_Descartes), a collaborative pseudonym of a few mathematicians. I was wondering if there is a standard way to address this using bibTeX?

If there's no standard for this, my idea was to put this information in a footnote within the bibliography, but that seems rather involved. Any suggestions? I'm looking for a relatively simple solution, as I'll probably want to submit this to a journal, and I'm not sure what templates/restrictions they'll have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a counterpoint to Mico's answer: AMS MathScinet treats all well-known collective pseudonyms (including Nicholas Bourbaki and Arthur Besse, as well as Blanche Descartes) as if they were real names. In the case of Blanche Descartes, this means the author fields in the corresponding BibTeX entries provided by MathSciNet all say

```
author = {Descartes, Blanche}
```

If you have access to MathSciNet, you can check to see if the articles you are referring to are indexed there and download corresponding BibTeX entries. (For your convenience, [here's a link to one of Descarte's papers in the MathSciNet Databse](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0026309).)